# Cannot find main.css under content folder once project is deployed

Tags: css, web-deployment

So basically I had this web project which had its content folder which in turn had folders like theme, style, etc.

And within style i had my main.css, main.css.min, etc. And when I would debug my application from visual studio, in the browser, in the javascript window (the one which we get on F12) i could see the exact same structure with all my css intact and applicable.

Now I have deployed my web app in Azure App Service. But now I see all my stylings are gone. When I checked the javascript window for the css, I see there is no such folder structure. I have the content, but inside that I have a folder called css, and inside that there is something called vendor. Where did my main.css, datatable.css files go?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the files are added to the project in Visual Studio. then right click the missing file in the project and go to properties, make sure that the Build Action is marked as "Content".

[image]